# Is it possible to filter a slice / map to a custom value with Goland Debugger

Tags: debugging, slice, goland

I manage slice that have thousands of structs inside.

To debug, I would like to have something like a filter that could allow me to filter a slice with a specific criteria.

Searching, I found that it can be done with Java since 2017 : https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/07/debugger-filtering-arrays-collections-in-intellij-idea-2017-2/

But with Goland, I can't find the option. Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: GoLand doesn't support filtering collections at the moment. Please feel free to file a feature request here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/GO if you think that it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to filter a slice / map to a custom value with Goland Debugger, function is not implemented on Goland.

An [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-9067) has been sent to Jetbrains.